# Yii2 Passing array values and storing the data in database table

Tags: arrays, database, model, yii2

In my project I want to save multiple data in seperate database table rows.

In my Controller action the code is below:

```
$deletedProducts = new \app\models\ProductlinesDeleted();
$app = \app\models\Productlines::find()
                                ->where(['product_id' => $id])->all();

        foreach ($app as $prod){
           $deletedProducts->productline_id = $prod->productline_id;
           $deletedProducts->area_id = $prod->area_id;
           $deletedProducts->product_id = $id;
           $deletedProducts->internal_code = $prod->internal_code;
           $deletedProducts->save();
           $prod->delete();
        }
          return $this->redirect(['index']);
```

The **$app** can return multiple products. SO based on that i want to save the data in the database table.

- Every product has an area_id.
- Every product will have a single area_id.

For example i have

- Product 1 with area 1
- Product 1 with area 2

So there are 2 products with different areas. When I perform the action, It has to save:

- Product 1 with area 1 in the database table row.
- Product 1 with area 2 in the database table next row.

  How can i achieve this?? Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
$app = \app\models\Productlines::find()
                                ->where(['product_id' => $id])->all();
    foreach ($app as $prod){
       $deletedProducts = new \app\models\ProductlinesDeleted();
       $deletedProducts->productline_id = $prod->productline_id;
       $deletedProducts->area_id = $prod->area_id;
       $deletedProducts->product_id = $id;
       $deletedProducts->internal_code = $prod->internal_code;
       $deletedProducts->save();
       $prod->delete();
    }
      return $this->redirect(['index']);
```

Comment: you created $deletedProducts  varible above the loop so every the existing record over written , and i put $deletedProducts in loop. so every time new object will be created and new record saved

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **beforeDelete** event inside your active record model file like

```
public function beforeDelete() {
  $deletedProducts = new \app\models\ProductlinesDeleted();
  $deletedProducts->productline_id = $this->productline_id;
  $deletedProducts->area_id = $this->area_id;
  $deletedProducts->product_id = $this->product_id;
  $deletedProducts->internal_code = $this->internal_code;
  $deletedProducts->save();

  return parent::beforeDelete();
}
```

This method will get call for each record of your table row. So for delete the product your code will be like

```
$products = \app\models\Productlines::find()->where(['product_id' => $id])->all();
foreach ($products as $prod){
   $prod->delete(); //beforeDelete event method will get call while you call this delete method.
}
return $this->redirect(['index']);
```

**Note:** beforeDelete event method will get call only if you are deleting a record by using above delete method.

Comment: Actually this is a part of my actionDelete(). I am passing area_id from my searchModel which i cannot pass that to beforeDelete() method. Based on  searchModel condition i delete the data. Anyways Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @MohanPrasad Actually finding the products and foreach loop will be inside your actionDelete() and beforeDelete will be inside the Productlines model file. For your reference - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeDelete()-detail. Anyway your problem get solved either way. all the best.